# Build a quiz/survey using SharePoint & Power Apps, which allow none-IT people to create questions and user to submit

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, powerapp, survey

I want to build a Quiz/Survey app using Power apps and SharePoint, as follow:-

1. We want admin users (none technical people) to be able to create questions and answers.
2. users will be answering the questions.
3. questions can have those types:-

- Free Text.
- Radio Buttons
- Checkboxes
- Yes/No

now i found this link @ https://www.spguides.com/powerapps-quiz-app/ .. but the only issue is that if we want to add additional questions or answers, then the user will have to modify the Power Apps. while we need things to happen on SharePoint list side, so non-IT people can add question and their answers. any advice?

Thanks

Comment: Microsoft Forms is made for this. It includes the ability to do quizzes and is designed to be easily edited by end users. All question types mentioned are supported. You can even integrate your forms into modern pages, Teams, and at specific moments during Streams. Forms can even be setup as templates to easily spawn new ones as needed. Unless you have specific reasons to go with Power Apps, I wouldn't use it for this. Power Apps will be harder to build, maintain, and collaborate on.

Comment: @theChrisKent I am open on using MS Forms, but i did not use them before.. so will MS forms allow us to define some business logic, such as if user answers questionX to redirect him to questionY ? if not to redirect them to QuestionZ and so on? also can we view all the forms results inside SharePoint list? or other data-sources?

Comment: Yes to branching and Yes to SharePoint list storage. Here's some 5 minute videos I made that should help: [Getting Started with Microsoft Forms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DtwFMLu3TJU), [Getting started with branching in Microsoft Forms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pf8un8IZ4Tw), and [Getting started on collecting your Microsoft Forms responses to SharePoint List](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TKL_KD4irf0)

Comment: @theChrisKent ok thanks for the video will check it,, but can external users access MS forms? second question is MS form responsive on mobile devices?

Comment: Yes, external users can access (adjust using settings for your form). Forms are automatically responsive for mobile usage and can easily be previewed while editing the form.

Comment: @theChrisKent do external users need license to access the MS Forms?

Comment: @theChrisKent also correct me if i am wrong, in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TKL_KD4irf0 it shows how to capture the results inside SharePoint list, and if the user add a new question inside the MS form, then the non-IT user will also need to modify the power automate action to populate the new question inside SharePoint , am i correct? which might be too much for non-IT user.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using [Microsoft Forms](https://forms.office.com/)? It is very easy to use but may not be fit for purpose if you need to do anything fancy.

Comment: I am open on using MS Forms, but i did not use them before.. so will MS forms allow us to define some business logic, such as if user answers questionX to redirect him to questionY ? if not to redirect them to QuestionZ and so on? also can we view all the forms results inside SharePoint list? or other data-sources?